# Virtual hosts breaking Apache

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, xampp, virtual-host

Running XAMP on Win 8 64. New machine.

Have been running XAMPP for a few weeks with work in sub directories hanging off htdocs without any real problems.

Downloaded a currently operational website and to make it work properly (document root addressing etc) wanted to create a simple virtual host setup. I did this once before with very clear, simple instructions without problems. This time found so much conflicting stuff and I cannot restart Apache after an edit of httpd.conf.

I get error message:

```
1:49:55 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:49:55 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
1:49:55 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:49:55 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:49:55 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:49:55 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
1:49:55 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I had edited etc in drivers to:

```
127.0.0.1       ot48
127.0.0.1       sanetext
127.0.0.1       saneText22
127.0.0.1       alohaenergy
127.0.0.1       unify
127.0.0.1       myexample
127.0.0.1       test  etc etc (10 directories)
```

Reading Apache info and other places edited httpd.conf to add:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/ot48
ServerName ot48.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/sanetext
ServerName sanetext.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/saneText22
ServerName saneText22.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/alohaenergy
ServerName alohaenergy.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

Grateful for any suggestions

EDIT Should have said that if I remove the edits in httpd.conf Apache starts no problem

Comment: Output of `httpd -t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want to use a [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) address for this. Use either an internal or external *real* address (or use nothing like I'll show you).

Try this Apache config setup:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ot48.loc
  ServerAlias ot48.loc *.ot48.loc
  DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/ot48
</VirtualHost>

..etc..
```

Also, you can simplify your hosts file by putting everything on one line, as so:

```
192.168.0.1   ot48.loc sanetext.loc saneText22.loc alohaenergy.loc unify.loc myexample.loc
```

Comment: Well I tried - still getting same error message. Looked in `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` looked in there and same format.... Tried 192. all in one line and 127. all in one line and back to multiple entries.

At a bit of a loss what to do next.

Comment: I just noticed that your hosts configuration doesn't include part of the address. This could very well be the problem. I've updated to show what it should probably look like. You can use PING on the command line to verify that these names are resolving correctly in the first place, `> PING ot48.loc` should return something like: `Pinging dev [192.168.1.1] with 32 bytes of data:`.... where 192.168.1.1 is your actual IP address.

Comment: Does it make any difference that I am using 127 or 192 - tried both. Ping just got `Ping request could not find host ot48.loc. Please check the name and try again.` NB Apache NOT running but hosts.txt updated.. Same old error message. BTW I forgot to say a big thanks for trying.

Comment: A-ha, you aren't editing the right file. It should be `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. This comes from the UNIX world so it DOES NOT have a file extension (you'll find that the default Windows settings make saving a file without an extension much more difficult, so [disable hiding them](http://www.howtohaven.com/system/show-file-extensions-in-windows-explorer.shtml)). When this is working, PING will show your correct IP (of the PC you are serving the webpage from).

Comment: BTW, a loopback address will work but serving webpages only makes sense if other computers can get to them which is why a loopback address is bad. IOW, use 192.*.*.*

Comment: Also, when you save the host file, make sure that the dropdown labeled `Save as type` in the save dialog has the option with `*.*` selected, otherwise it'll save it as a `*.TXT` file anyway.

Comment: OK fantastic not sure how I added .txt but easily fixed and ping works fine (127.0.0.1 ) BUT still get the error.

Comment: Try disabling any firewalls you may have enabled on that machine. If that fixes the problem then worry about configuring it to allow port 80 through.

Comment: Also, DO NOT use an IP in the apache config. Use only * for now. When you have this working you can tighten down the security and only allow certain network interfaces to be used.

Comment: Nope McAfee and Win Firewall off. Apache access and error logs seem to show nothing. Went into Win Event Viewer - not sure what I was looking for but could not see any obvious reports. System is saying "would I like to move to a chat". I am new here I'm leave that up to u or do I have to originate.

Comment: We've covered the simple stuff. Now you need to go through [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html) and try everything it says to.

Comment: It **WAS** the simple stuff. Pretty sure it was an extra `</VirtualHost>`. Cleaned out the `httpd.conf` file and then loaded up the `vhosts` file in extra. Couple of `vhosts` at a time until the fail and noticed the mistake.

Comment: The only final tweak was to add `<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>` as first listing to get plain `localhost` working again